yq utility fails with error: unknown shorthand flag: 'c' in -c
I am trying to use yq utility to parse for validation values.yaml files, the resources block in particular. Below is a simple gitlab ci pipeline that I created to test yq utility
stages:
  - test

check_values_files:
  stage: test
  image: mikefarah/yq:latest
  script: >
    - for f in .helm/values_*.*ml; 
        do echo "Checking resources in ${f}";
        if yq e '.resources.requests' ${f} > /dev/null && yq e '.resources.limits' ${f} > /dev/null; 
        then echo "resources.requests and resources.limits found in ${f}";
        else
          echo "Error: Missing resources.requests or resources.limits in ${f}";
          exit 1;
        fi;
      done

The image yq is loading successfully, but I get an error as below
Error: unknown shorthand flag: 'c' in -c

Below is an output of the pipeline
Running with gitlab-runner 17.0.0~pre.88.g761ae5dd (761ae5dd)
  on green-6.saas-linux-small-amd64.runners-manager.gitlab.com/default YKxHNyexq, system ID: s_a201ab37b78a
Preparing the "docker+machine" executor
00:06
Using Docker executor with image mikefarah/yq:latest ...
Pulling docker image mikefarah/yq:latest ...
Using docker image sha256:43d24fadfe38b397aa7180c3fe99af5bd7f6e39ffc47a6b01219d85c59b53c14 for mikefarah/yq:latest with digest mikefarah/yq@sha256:2ecaeeff15976cd00c4627f119b592b5c9311b7080beff469211606c42c6cbd2 ...
Preparing environment
00:00
Running on runner-ykxhnyexq-project-60345318-concurrent-0 via runner-ykxhnyexq-s-l-s-amd64-1721942466-69b4fb21...
Getting source from Git repository
00:01
Fetching changes with git depth set to 20...
Initialized empty Git repository in /builds/devops9712901/yq/.git/
Created fresh repository.
Checking out 74cd916e as detached HEAD (ref is main)...
Skipping Git submodules setup
$ git remote set-url origin "${CI_REPOSITORY_URL}"
Executing "step_script" stage of the job script
00:01
Using docker image sha256:43d24fadfe38b397aa7180c3fe99af5bd7f6e39ffc47a6b01219d85c59b53c14 for mikefarah/yq:latest with digest mikefarah/yq@sha256:2ecaeeff15976cd00c4627f119b592b5c9311b7080beff469211606c42c6cbd2 ...
Error: unknown shorthand flag: 'c' in -c
Usage:
  yq eval [expression] [yaml_file1]... [flags]
Aliases:
  eval, e
Examples:
# Reads field under the given path for each file
yq e '.a.b' f1.yml f2.yml 
# Prints out the file
yq e sample.yaml 
# Pipe from STDIN
## use '-' as a filename to pipe from STDIN
cat file2.yml | yq e '.a.b' file1.yml - file3.yml
# Creates a new yaml document
## Note that editing an empty file does not work.
yq e -n '.a.b.c = "cat"' 
# Update a file in place
yq e '.a.b = "cool"' -i file.yaml 
Flags:
  -h, --help   help for eval
Global Flags:
  -C, --colors                        force print with colors
      --csv-auto-parse                parse CSV YAML/JSON values (default true)
      --csv-separator char            CSV Separator character (default ,)
  -e, --exit-status                   set exit status if there are no matches or null or false is returned
      --expression string             forcibly set the expression argument. Useful when yq argument detection thinks your expression is a file.
      --from-file string              Load expression from specified file.
  -f, --front-matter string           (extract|process) first input as yaml front-matter. Extract will pull out the yaml content, process will run the expression against the yaml content, leaving the remaining data intact
      --header-preprocess             Slurp any header comments and separators before processing expression. (default true)
  -I, --indent int                    sets indent level for output (default 2)
  -i, --inplace                       update the file in place of first file given.
  -p, --input-format string           [auto|a|yaml|y|json|j|props|p|csv|c|tsv|t|xml|x|base64|uri|toml|lua|l] parse format for input. (default "auto")
      --lua-globals                   output keys as top-level global variables
      --lua-prefix string             prefix (default "return ")
      --lua-suffix string             suffix (default ";\n")
      --lua-unquoted                  output unquoted string keys (e.g. {foo="bar"})
  -M, --no-colors                     force print with no colors
  -N, --no-doc                        Don't print document separators (---)
  -0, --nul-output                    Use NUL char to separate values. If unwrap scalar is also set, fail if unwrapped scalar contains NUL char.
  -n, --null-input                    Don't read input, simply evaluate the expression given. Useful for creating docs from scratch.
  -o, --output-format string          [auto|a|yaml|y|json|j|props|p|csv|c|tsv|t|xml|x|base64|uri|toml|shell|s|lua|l] output format type. (default "auto")
  -P, --prettyPrint                   pretty print, shorthand for '... style = ""'
      --properties-array-brackets     use [x] in array paths (e.g. for SpringBoot)
      --properties-separator string   separator to use between keys and values (default " = ")
  -s, --split-exp string              print each result (or doc) into a file named (exp). [exp] argument must return a string. You can use $index in the expression as the result counter.
      --split-exp-file string         Use a file to specify the split-exp expression.
      --string-interpolation          Toggles strings interpolation of \(exp) (default true)
      --tsv-auto-parse                parse TSV YAML/JSON values (default true)
  -r, --unwrapScalar                  unwrap scalar, print the value with no quotes, colors or comments. Defaults to true for yaml (default true)
  -v, --verbose                       verbose mode
      --xml-attribute-prefix string   prefix for xml attributes (default "+@")
      --xml-content-name string       name for xml content (if no attribute name is present). (default "+content")
      --xml-directive-name string     name for xml directives (e.g. <!DOCTYPE thing cat>) (default "+directive")
      --xml-keep-namespace            enables keeping namespace after parsing attributes (default true)
      --xml-proc-inst-prefix string   prefix for xml processing instructions (e.g. <?xml version="1"?>) (default "+p_")
      --xml-raw-token                 enables using RawToken method instead Token. Commonly disables namespace translations. See https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/xml#Decoder.RawToken for details. (default true)
      --xml-skip-directives           skip over directives (e.g. <!DOCTYPE thing cat>)
      --xml-skip-proc-inst            skip over process instructions (e.g. <?xml version="1"?>)
      --xml-strict-mode               enables strict parsing of XML. See https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/xml for more details.
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables
00:01
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1

I'm not sure what I am missing, and I don't see where I am using a flag it's complaining about. I tried different yq image versions and got the same result. Can someone please help me here?

It can potentially happen, when your yq filter expression contains a value that starts with a -. It is not clear if thats the issue you hit as well. You can get around it, by doing -- after yq, which indicates to not process strings after it as command line arguments yq e -- '...'

Thank you for your reply, unfortunately, the same result I got. I'm going to debug it.
